# How do I calculate machine uptime using mdx?

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

Suppose I have some servers in a datacenter and some technicians that support those servers. Each technician has a unique set of servers to support. I have a data warehouse and OLAP cube that contains the technicians and servers as dimensions. As facts, it contains the downtimes for each server. These are numbers of seconds on a given day (the day points to a classic date dimension).

I would like to compute server uptime percentage by technician. I can easily compute uptime percentage for each individual server per by simply writing an mdx expression that divides the downtime seconds per day / seconds in a day. This can be done across any range of days for a server to get its percentage uptime.

Where I'm stuck is in rolling this up to the technician that manages those servers. I think the solution is that I must add a new fact to my warehouse that tells me the total number of active servers for each technician per day so that I can compute total downtime / total active server seconds for each technician. This would be analogous to the "inventory snapshot" fact that Kimball describes in his data warehousing book.

Is there some other approach I should be considering?

Answer (score 0):

MDX/the cube should take care of that. Just add the technicians to e. g. the rows or columns of your MDX query, and the breakdown should be there.

That is why you link the dimensions to the fact tables in your cube design. After you did this, you do not have to care about that in MDX queries.

Comment: Yeah, I already have my technician dimensions properly linked to my server downtime facts. But, I'm lacking any fact information about how many active servers each technician supports, which is necessary for calculating total percent uptime across all servers.

Comment: Can you post the the MDX you have so far, as well as the structure of your cube, including the measures and the names of the dimensions and attributes relevant for this query? Then it would be much easier to communicate about it without having to imagine names etc.